# SQL Pivot Table - Subqueries

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I have a program that is logging the time a user spends on certain aspects, some are identified as specific "time". I'm struggling to get multiple lines of Grouped query results into a single line for each month as a "summary".

My current query:

```
SELECT
    TotalMins  = SUM(Minutes)
    ,DateMonth = MONTH(Date)
    ,ID1
    ,PC
FROM User_Time_Log
WHERE
    (UserID = 1)
    AND (YEAR(Date) = 2018)
GROUP BY
    MONTH(Date)
    ,ID1
    ,PC1
```

Current results:

```
TotalMins   DateMonth   ID1         PC1
192         1           0           0
306         1           0           100
113         2           0           0
365         2           0           100
14          2           1           0
3           2           1           100
75          3           0           0
253         3           0           100
3           3           1           0
300         4           0           0
233         4           0           100
10          4           1           0
23          4           1           100
438         5           0           0
134         5           0           100
19          5           1           0
49          5           1           100
0           9           1           0
11          10          0           0
21          10          0           60
167         10          1           100
```

What I would like to do from this point is to create a table showing all 12 months, regardless of whether there is information within that month or not, and show the relative information within each row for that month. for example:

```
DateMonth       NonID1      TimeID1     TimePC1 (Round((PC1/100)*TotalMins)) TimePC1ID1
1               192             0               306             0
2               113             14              365             3
3               75              3               253             0
4               300             10              233             23              
5               438             19              134             49
6               0               0               0               0
7               0               0               0               0
8               0               0               0               0   
9               0               0               0               0
10              11              0               13              167
11              0               0               0               0
12              0               0               0               0
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Note: I have also created a table to give me 1-12 as rows that I can use to give me the months that I need to use, where information is not within the user_time_log.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you need to do. Use your table with 12 rows as the base for your query and left join to the other User_Time_Log table query that you have. Just move the where clause to your join predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do what you're looking for:

First, create your table of month values. I made a simple temp table with a single column.

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (MonthNum INT)
INSERT INTO #Dates
(
    MonthNum
)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
```

Next, you can put your existing query into a CTE, then `LEFT JOIN` to your table of months. You'll want to put your columns into a `SUM`'d `CASE` statement, like so:

```
;WITH Aggregation AS
(
    SELECT
    TotalMins  = SUM(Minutes)
    ,DateMonth = MONTH(Date)
    ,ID1
    ,PC1
FROM #User_Time_Log
WHERE
    (UserID = 1)
    AND (YEAR(Date) = 2018)
GROUP BY
    MONTH(Date)
    ,ID1
    ,PC1
)
SELECT 
    d.MonthNum 
    ,NonID1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 0 THEN TotalMins ELSE 0 END)
    ,TimeID1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 1 THEN TotalMins ELSE 0 END)
    ,TimePC1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 0 THEN ROUND((PC1/100)*TotalMins,0) ELSE 0 END) 
    ,TimePC1ID1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 1 THEN ROUND((PC1/100)*TotalMins,0) ELSE 0 END) 
FROM #Dates d
LEFT JOIN Aggregation a ON d.MonthNum = a.DateMonth
GROUP BY d.MonthNum
```

Output would then look like this:

```
MonthNum    NonID1  TimeID1 TimePC1 TimePC1ID1
1           498     0       306     0
2           478     17      365     3
3           328     3       253     0
4           533     33      233     23
5           572     68      134     49
6           0       0       0       0
7           0       0       0       0
8           0       0       0       0
9           0       0       0       0
10          32      167     0       167
11          0       0       0       0
12          0       0       0       0
```

EDIT:

The `ROUND()` function call can be changed slightly to accomodate your need for decimal results. The first parameter of `ROUND()` is the expression you want to round, and the second is the number of decimal places to round to. Positive numbers indicate the number of places to the right of the decimal to round to. Negative numbers indicate the number of places to the left of the decimal to round to. So if you set it to `2`, you'll get an answer rounded to the nearest hundredth.

But there's one more tweak we need. `PC1` and `TotalMins` are both assumed to be `INT`s in my answer. So we have to give the SQL engine a little help so that it calculates the answer as a `DECIMAL`. By `CAST()`ing the `INT`s to `DECIMAL`s, SQL will perform the arithmetic op as decimal math instead of integer math. You'd just have to change `TimePC1` and `TimePC1ID1` like so:

```
,TimePC1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 0 THEN ROUND((CAST(PC1 AS DECIMAL)/100)*CAST(TotalMins AS DECIMAL),2) ELSE 0 END) 
,TimePC1ID1 = SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = 1 THEN ROUND((CAST(PC1 AS DECIMAL)/100)*CAST(TotalMins AS DECIMAL),2) ELSE 0 END)
```

Then the output looks like this:

```
MonthNum    NonID1  TimeID1 TimePC1     TimePC1ID1
1           498     0       306.000000  0.000000
2           478     17      365.000000  3.000000
3           328     3       253.000000  0.000000
4           533     33      233.000000  23.000000
5           572     68      134.000000  49.000000
6           0       0       0.000000    0.000000
7           0       0       0.000000    0.000000
8           0       0       0.000000    0.000000
9           0       0       0.000000    0.000000
10          32      167     12.600000   167.000000
11          0       0       0.000000    0.000000
12          0       0       0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for this Aaron.
I appear to be having another difficulty with the Round  part of this calculation.
I have a figure of 31 minutes to be rounded by 60%, yet the result I get is 0.

I have tried casting both the percentage calc and also everything inside the "round" parenthesis as decimal to 2 places, but still only get 0 returned.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Just had to cast the outside the round as an int to bring it back to an integer.
Again, thank you!